# ScrollView is not scrolling in fragment or not working properly

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm pretty new in android and I'm developing an app but I have an error that's driving me crazy. The thing is that it doesn't scroll completely, it leaves a button out of the screen so it cant be seen.
Scrollview works fine in every activity but doesn't work in tabbed activity.
this code `android:layout_height="match_parent"` is giving problem if i change the height match-parent to 500dp or to any integer value it works fine. I want to know that why match-parent is not working.

i have tried every suggested edit to this question but still no edit works.

here is my XML file

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@mipmap/back"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
tools:context="com.example.sahil.bloodbank.first"
>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/sc1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="Welcome,"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/wall1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/data"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textColor="@color/data"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/note"
        android:textColor="@color/data"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/donate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="I want to Donate Blood"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/data"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not need to take *Scroll View* as *Root Layout* not required. But you may need to add more properties to *Scroll View* like `android:scrollbars="vertical"` and `android:fillViewport="true"`. Also you can use approach like you take `Button` outside of `Scroll View` and only scroll other content so your `Button` always will be visible on screen only your content will scroll.

Like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_above="@+id/donate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Welcome,"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/desc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Description DescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescription"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/data"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/desc"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:text=" Note DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote DataNote Data"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textStyle="bold" />



        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/donate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="I want to Donate Blood"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Inside `Fragment` you can try this property `android:isScrollContainer="false"` inside `Scroll View`.

If that not work try with `NestedScrollView` in `Fragment`.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fillViewport="true"
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: scrollview works fine in every activity but it doesn't work fine in fragments.

Comment: scrolling works if i set height of scrollview manually like  
      `android:layout_height="500dp"` but doesn't works when `android:layout_height="match_parent/wrap_content"`

Comment: @sahilchauhan Button is showing and it will show up to bottom all your content is above that button i have tested it scrolling content above button.

Comment: @sahilchauhan I did tried based on what ever you explained in your question not tried with tabbed activity and all that.

Comment: i change the code as you suggested but stills not working in tabbed activity.

Comment: it works fine in any activity other than tabbed activity

Comment: scrolling works fine in preview but when i install it on phone then scrolling stops working.

Comment: it worked actually i wont look at your edit properly.

Comment: @sahilchauhan Accept answer like https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png this and upvote answer so it will be helpful to future visitors.

Comment: in my case, i haven't added `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to my activity in `manifest` file, after adding it, now my `scrollview` is working now..

Answer (score 0):

Scroll view must be the root element.

```
<ScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.sahil.bloodbank.first"
>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@mipmap/back"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="Welcome,"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/wall1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/data"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textColor="@color/data"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/note"
        android:textColor="@color/data"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/donate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="I want to Donate Blood"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/data"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

your scrollview must be the MATCHPARENT height

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: its not working in fragment. but works fine in other activity(empty,basic,etc)

Comment: that is weird;
there no difference between fragment and activity; in LinearLayout, change "height" from "match_parent" to "wrap_content" and test if it works

Comment: is your scrollview clickable?

Answer (score 0):

Make your Scrollview as root view and height should be MATCH_PARENT

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Welcome,"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/wall1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/data"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="@color/data"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/note"
            android:textColor="@color/data"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/donate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="I want to Donate Blood"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/data"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: main problem is that scrollview is not working in fragments. but works fine in any other activity

Comment: Okay let me check

Comment: check it in tabbed activity

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and change this code accroding your need and make sure your view is large to screen size after that scrolling effect is occur.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:clickable="true">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/layout_padding">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/epfIvUserImage"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/big_user" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/epfEtFirstName"
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user"
        android:hint="@string/user_name"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        android:nextFocusForward="@id/epfEtEmail"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/epfEtEmail"
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:nextFocusForward="@id/epfEtCountry"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/epfEtCountry"
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/country"
        android:hint="@string/country"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:nextFocusForward="@id/epfEtState"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/epfEtState"
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/state"
        android:hint="@string/state"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:nextFocusForward="@id/epfEtCity"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/epfEtCity"
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/city"
        android:hint="@string/city"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:nextFocusForward="@id/epfEtPincode"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/epfEtPincode"
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/street"
        android:hint="@string/zip_code"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:nextFocusForward="@id/epfEtDescription"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/epfEtDescription"
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/descriptions"
        android:hint="@string/description"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_30sdp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/epfTvUpdate"
        android:text="@string/update"
        style="@style/TextViewButton"
        />


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: scrollview works fine in every activity but it doesn't work fine in fragments.

Comment: scrolling works if i set height of scrollview manually like android:layout_height="500dp" but doesn't works when android:layout_height="match_parent/wrap_content"

Comment: this code is working into fragment and activity both.

Answer (score 0):

The standard ScrollView need to be used as parent. I think you are using ToolBar in your activity.
So in that case you can use [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView) with the attribute
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

So replace your ScrollView with:---

```
<NestedScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:fillViewport="true"
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

  {Your Child View}

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: let me try this